# How can I start fullscreen in safari using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen

I am using this code to start and stop fullscreen:

```
function fullscreen() {
    full = document.getElementById("full");
    if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitIsFullScreen && !document.msFullscreenElement) {
        elem = document.getElementById("body");
        if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
            elem.requestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
            elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
            elem.msRequestFullscreen();
        }
    } else {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
            document.webkitExitFullscreen();
        } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
            document.msExitFullscreen();
        }
    }
}
```

It works in every browser but Safari. I read that `elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();` is for Safari. So how get I this to work in Safari? Whole Website: [jnnx.de/sia.html](https://jnnx.de/sia.html)

Comment: Can you verify that you have a supported version of Safari? https://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen

Comment: Are you using Mac or iOS Safari? It's supposed to be supported on Macs.

Comment: I'm using safari on iOS

Answer (score 1):

Fullscreen is not supported in Safari for iOS. Thanks to @GenericUser

Answer (score 0):

You could make a simple app and use Apple’s WebKit framework. (If it is for internal use..)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Safari with iOS 12.1+ on an iPad, the fullscreen api has been enabled but hidden behind the "webkit" prefix (webkitRequestFullscreen, webkitExitFullscreen, etc).

**To enter fullscreen in this way, you must (usually) make several interactions before it activate.**

This API (as far as I can tell) has not been finalised, and has some odd behaviour and quirks. Given a few months it may change or be opened up to other devices and/or browsers, but for now **only works on the iOS 12.1+ version of Safari on an iPad.**

On devices running iOS 12.1+, this API can be disabled/enabled through the Safari settings page under "Settings > Safari > Advanced > Experimental Features > Toggle Fullscreen API".